# What is the best way to pass an unordered_map from a mex file back to a .m file?

Tags: matlab, hash, mex

I would like to create an unordered_map in a mex file and pass it back to a Matlab caller for further processing. What is the best way to accomplish this in terms of performance?

p.s.1. This hashtable is HUGE!

p.s.2. containers.Map is extremely slow and java.util.hashtable is very slow for what I am doing.

Comment: What are your key, value types ? How big is HUGE ? Millions, hundreds of millions of <Key,Value> pairs ? Is this calling C/C++ (MEX API) or calling into Java from Matlab ? Which one is the requirement, a bit confusing as these two are very different ?

Comment: Do you want to pass in the table to the (external) function or (create and) persist the table through multiple calls across language boundaries ? Also, how slow is slow, how long is the execution and what kind of performance gains are you looking for ?

Comment: @SaharshBishnoi Sorry for the delayed answer. It can contain hundreds of millions of <Key,Value> pairs. My program has a 3-level nested loop, which is slowing my program down a lot (a day to extract the information I want which gets stored in a hashtable). I would like to call C/C++ (MEX API) as it helps a lot with the performance of my program and pass it back to matlab caller without having to save it to external storage and read it later.